# Accessing Plist Arrays / Nodes - Objective C

Tags: iphone, arrays, string, plist

I have a Property List file that I'm using to store questions and answer data. Within this file I have a collection of arrays, within these I store the different categories and questions. However I can't seem to access this data?

The property file;

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN"  "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
<key>Category1</key>
<array>
    <array>
        <string>Question1</string>
        <string>Answer1</string>
    </array>
    <array>
        <string>Question2</string>
        <string>Answer2</string>
    </array>
    <array>
        <string>Question3</string>
        <string>Answer3</string>
    </array>
    <array>
        <string>Question4</string>
        <string>Answer4</string>
    </array>
</array>
</dict>
</plist>
```

Below I'm using to access the property list file by stepping through it using two simple buttons;

```
-(IBAction)nextleft {
    [self bingsound];
    if (questionCounter > 1) {
        questionCounter -= 1;
    }
    [self nextQuestion];
}

-(IBAction)nextright {
    [self bingsound];
     if (questionCounter < 20) {
         questionCounter += 1;
     }
     [self nextQuestion];
}

-(void)nextQuestion {
    NSArray *pair;
    pair = [categories objectAtIndex:questionCounter];
    plistQuestion = [pair objectAtIndex:0];
    plistAnswer = [pair objectAtIndex:1];
    abbreviation.text = plistQuestion;
}
```

I'm populating the the category array as follows;

```
categories = [NSArray arrayWithContentsOfFile:@"questions.plist"];
```

Comment: Can you open your property list in a text editor, and post the opening lines? That screenshot doesn't look right, the first entry should be called "Root", which is not normally editable through the plist editor. You've either got an invalid property list or a dictionary as the root object - in the debugger, check what your categories array is initialised to.

Comment: Just added that now for you to take a look at.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your property list has a dictionary as the root object, not an array.

Remove these lines from the top:

```
<dict>
<key>Category1</key>
```

And this line from the end:

```
</dict>
```

Also, follow @murat's advice and derive a correct path to your file instead of a plain string.

In general with issues like this, the debugger is your friend. Put a breakpoint in your method and check at each stage (deriving the path, extracting the array) what values you are getting out.

Comment: Thanks for the help, simple fix as I suspected and after ironing out a few problems it worked a treat. Thanks!

Comment: You should ask a separate question.

Answer (score 1):

You should provide `arrayWithContentsOfFile:` with the full path to the plist file. The following should work:

```
NSString* filePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"questions" ofType:@"plist"];
categories = [NSArray arrayWithContentsOfFile:filePath];
```